# How Do I Trim A String When It Reaches A Certain Character (Parenthesis)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

[image]

I have this column with a string inside of it. I want to return a result that shows the provider column with all characters inside of it up, but not including, the space before the first open parenthesis.

What is the best strategy for accomplishing this?

i.e. turn "NEAL K HANSEN (4406570001)" to "NEAL K HANSEN" and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexp_replace()`, like this:

```
regexp_replace(provider, ' \([^)]*\)', '')
```

For example:

```
=> select regexp_replace('"NEAL K HANSEN (4406570001)"', ' \([^)]*\)', '');
regexp_replace
-----------------
"NEAL K HANSEN"
(1 row)
```

The function call replaces everything matching "a space, an open paren, any number of characters that is not a closing paren, and a closing paren" with nothing (an empty string).

Comment: Awesome, this works great. I'll read up on the documentation here since you led me to the right place. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP